# ITfoxtec SAML Library Services.BindConfig -- error

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using the ITfoxtec SAML2 Library and following the example from the site
I see they have an extension method BindConfig
however, in my use of the library I am getting an error IServicesCollection does not contain a definition for BindConfig
I am using

using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2;

using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore;

using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore.Configuration;

using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas.Metadata;

using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Util;

```
services.BindConfig<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration, "Saml2", (serviceProvider, saml2Configuration) =>
        {
            ......
         }
```

Is this related to the Binding error with .net 5.0 by any chance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding method read your [`Saml2` configuration](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L10) in `appsettings.json`
Maybe you are missing the configuration.